# How to change fill color SVG object for specific path id via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

svg:

```
  <path id="svg_1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" d="m50.610001,63.470001l12.869999,0m0,0l0,464.709991m0,0l-12.869999,0m0,0l0,-464.709991"/>
  <path id="svg_2" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" d="m66.529999,260.670013l12.870003,0m0,0l-0.029999,267.519989m0,0l-12.870003,0m0,0l0.029999,-267.519989"/>
  <path id="svg_3" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" d="m66.519997,275.440002l-3.039997,0"/>
```

html:

```
<div ng-include="'example.svg'"></div>
```

I would like to change fill color for id="svg_2" for example on button click, How to do it?

Comment: please show the demo that demonstrates your problem. You can grab this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/77oUelWE5fS6IxzdqB3H?p=preview&preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your paths. After every line you are using a move to command (`m`) where you are moving to the last point. I've rewritten the first 2 paths bu removing the move to (`m0,0`) Now the paths can be filled. The third path is just a line.

Now you can fill the paths using css or bu resetting the value of the attribute `fill`

```css
path{fill:red}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 130 600" width="100">
<path id="svg_1" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M50.610001,63.470001l12.869999,0
   l0,464.709991
   l-12.869999,0
   l0,-464.709991"/>
  <path id="svg_2" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M66.529999,260.670013l12.870003,0
   l-0.029999,267.519989
   l-12.870003,0
   l0.029999,-267.519989"/>
  <path id="svg_3" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" d="m66.519997,275.440002l-3.039997,0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I no need to fill all paths, but only path "svg_2"

Comment: In this case you can select only the second path and fill it. The problem you have is the way you coded your paths. You need to fix that problem. Then fill whatever you need.